# Solving differential equation using Bertrand's theorem and Fourier

Tags: classical-mechanics, angular-momentum, orbital-motion, fourier-transform, centrifugal-force

So I had a equation :
$$m\ddot r=\frac{e^2}{r^2}-\frac{l^2}{mr^3}$$
This was obtained via Hamilton's equation on a Bohr atom. I read somewhere that this has a complex yet periodic solution, as proven by Bertrand's theorem, and that we can write a closed form of $r(t)$ using Fourier series.
Any help that can provide clarification about this, like what the closed form might be is appreciated. P.S: I am not familiar with any of the Fourier stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that you have the right sign before the $e^2/r^2-l^2/mr^3$ term... Surely for an attractive force we have
$$
m\ddot r= -\frac{e^2}{r^2} +\frac{l^2}{mr^3}?
$$
In any case, if you set $r=1/u$ you should get a simple equation for $d^2u/{d\theta^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

From here

$$m\,\frac{dv}{dt}=-\frac{e^2}{r^2}+\frac{l^2}{m\,r^3}\quad \Rightarrow\\
m\,\frac{dv}{dt}\,v=-\frac{e^2}{r^2}+\frac{l^2}{m\,r^3}\,\frac{dr}{dt}\\
\int m\,{dv}\,v=-\int \left(\frac{e^2}{r^2}+\frac{l^2}{m\,r^3}\right)\,{dr}\quad \Rightarrow\\
v(r)=\frac{\sqrt{l^2-2\,e^2\,m\,r}}{m\,r}
$$

$~ r(t) ~$ ?

with:

$$\frac{dr}{dt}=v(r)\quad\Rightarrow\\
\int \frac{1}{v(r)}\,dr=t\quad \Rightarrow$$

$$r(t)=r_0+\frac 12\,\left(-{\frac {{l}^{2}}{m{e}^{2}}}-{\frac { \left( 3\,tm{e}^{4}+\sqrt {-{l}^
{6}+9\,{t}^{2}{m}^{2}{e}^{8}} \right) ^{2/3}}{m{e}^{2}}}-{\frac {{l}^{
4}}{m{e}^{2} \left( 3\,tm{e}^{4}+\sqrt {-{l}^{6}+9\,{t}^{2}{m}^{2}{e}^
{8}} \right) ^{2/3}}}
\right)
$$

the differential equation

$$m\,\frac{d^2\,r}{dt^2}=-\frac{e^2}{r^2}+\frac{l^2}{m\,r^3}\mapsto\\
m\,\frac{d^2\,u}{d\varphi^2}+u(\varphi)=\frac{e^2\,m}{l^2}$$

where $~u(\varphi)=\frac{1}{r(\varphi)}~$

the solution is

$$\frac{1}{r} ={\frac {b\cos \left( \varphi -\varphi _{{0}
} \right) {e}^{2}m}{{l}^{2}}}+{\frac {{e}^{2}m}{{l}^{2}}}
$$

where $~b~$  and $~\varphi_0~$ are the initial conditions